# If $\operatorname{trcl}(x) \in L_\alpha$ , then $x \in L_\alpha$

Tags: set-theory

$L_\alpha$ here denotes the $\alpha$ stage of the constructible universe, and $\operatorname{trcl}(x)$ is the $\in$-transitive closure of $x$. Is this true for every ordinal $\alpha$? I tried proving by induction, and clearly the cases $\alpha = 0$ and limit ordinal are direct, but I'm not sure how to proceed when $\operatorname{trcl}(x) \in L_{\alpha+1} = Def(L_\alpha)$. One can also argue that since $L_\alpha$ is transitive, $x \subset\operatorname{trcl}(x) \subset L_\alpha$, but I can't conclude anything from that.

Comment: This isn't true in general. The transitive closure of an unbounded set of natural numbers is $\omega$. And $\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$. At the same time, the set of natural numbers coding the theory of $L_\omega$ is not an element of $L_{\omega+1}$ by Tarski undefinability, and yet its transitive closure is.

Comment: It would be interesting if we can characterize $\alpha$ with such property. I can see that if $\alpha$ is admissible, then $L_\alpha$ satisfies separation (in fact, $L$ thinks $L_\alpha$ satisfies the second-order separation) and $\Sigma_1$-replacement. I have no idea we can go further, however.

Comment: @HanulJeon working in $L$, the ordinals satisfying this property are exactly the cardinals. First, if $kappa$ is a cardinal, then $L_\kappa=H_\kappa$. And $trcl(x)\in L_\kappa$ just implies $x$  is in $H_\kappa$. Now if $\alpha$ is not a cardinal, then take some $X\subseteq |\alpha|$ which comes in $L$ at a stage later than $L_\alpha$. The transitive closure of such an $X$ is just $|\alpha|$, which is in $L_\alpha$.

Comment: @Jason Nice proof. How about making your arguments as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this claim isn't true in general. The transitive closure of an unbounded set of natural numbers is $\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$. At the same time, the set of natural numbers coding the theory of $L_\omega$ is not an element of $L_{\omega+1}$ by Tarski undefinability, and yet its transitive closure is. Or for that matter, the argument can be carried out for any real, including those not in $L$.

On the other hand, assuming $V=L$, an ordinal $\alpha$ satisfying "$trcl(x)\in L_\alpha\rightarrow x\in L_\alpha$" if and only if $\alpha$ is a cardinal.

To see this, first recall if $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then $L_\kappa=H_\kappa$. And $trcl(x)∈L_\kappa$ just implies $x\in H_\kappa$. Conversely, if $\alpha$ is not a cardinal, then take some $X\subseteq|\alpha|$ which comes in $L$ at a stage later than $L_\alpha$. The transitive closure of such an $X$ is just $|\alpha|$, which is in $L_\alpha$. But by the choice of $X$, we have that $X\notin L_\alpha$.